# Should [Oracle-18c] tag be added?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, version-tags

I see that we have version-specific tags for Oracle:

- [oracle-10g](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-10g) with 13 questions
- [oracle-11g](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g) with 89 questions
- [oracle-12c](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-12c) with 11 questions

Do we need to add a tag for Oracle 18c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are looking at some Oracle tags then I think it may be worth looking at them in context with all our Oracle tags.

If you use `[*oracle*]` in the search bar it expands to `[oracle] or [oracle-spatial] or [oracle-11g] or [oracle-10g] or [oracle-12c] or [cx-oracle] or [oracle-map-builder]`

In total there are 627 questions with an Oracle tag on them.  The counts on those not already in your question are:

- [oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) with 359 questions
- [oracle-spatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-spatial) with 228 questions
- [cx-oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cx-oracle) with 4 questions
- [oracle-map-builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-map-builder) with 3 questions

I used to be a strong advocate of version tags but over time I have seen them having less and less value.  Nowadays I think the best, and usually the only, place for mentioning software versions is in the question body.

Rather than creating a new Oracle version tag I propose that we move towards an Oracle tagging scheme along these lines:

- [oracle-dbms](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-dbms) for non-spatial use of Oracle - tag being created by rename of current [oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [oracle-spatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-spatial) for Oracle Spatial and Oracle Locator

To get to this we could:

1. synonymize the Oracle version tags with Oracle Spatial, or go through them to disambiguate and re-tag them as Oracle Spatial or Oracle DBMS
2. burninate the CX Oracle and Oracle Map Builder tags
3. once the [oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag has been emptied out make it a synonym of [oracle-spatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-spatial)

I make the above proposal as a rare user of Oracle and hope that our Oracle users will join us in this discussion.